# How can Jenkins help to implement CI/CD for Drupal?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, drupal

Assume you want to implement [continuous-integration](/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) (= CI) and [continuous-deployment](/questions/tagged/continuous-deployment) (= CD) for building and maintaining websites using [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal) (let's assume for Drupal Version 7). Often times Jenkins seems to be recommended as one of the most appropriate solutions for doing so.

But what kind of CI/CD related functionality can I actually use it for? Here are some of things I'm thinking of, but I'm not sure if I'm correct on that, and/or if these are the only things:

- CI related: Automated testing.
- CD related: Migrating custom module development between dev / staging / QA environments.

Comment: In my job we are trying to use Ansible + DrupalVM + Jenkins in our environment.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer maybe you should post an answer to (briefly) explain each of those 3 things?

Comment: I'm not the expert in this topic, but I will ask for some information about how this worls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've listed is actually two different things, continuous delivery and continuous integration.  When people talk about CI they typically are only referring to the testing part; automated unit, function, and integration testing with some sort of version bump or code promotion at the end.  Looks like the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Drupal+Development) has some specific pointers about Drupal.

As far as environment promotion, you're getting into continuous delivery which Jenkins can also be used for.  Consider looking at the more modern [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) for CD pipelines.